# Is an integral manifold N of a distribution $\Delta$ over M always a submanifold of M?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have the following definition from Boothby:

"If $\Delta$ is a $C^\infty$ distribution on M and N is a connected  $C^\infty$ submanifold of M such that for each $q\in N$ we have $T_q(N)\subset\Delta_q$, then we shall say that N is an integral manifold of $\Delta$."

Now if N is and integral manifold of $\Delta$ do I necessarily have that N is a submanifold of M?

Comment: Yes, it's part of the definition!

Comment: All right, thanks! I think I can see that now.

Comment: Note that this means it's an *immersed* submanifold. There's no reason for it to be embedded, except locally.

Comment: For it to be an embedded manifold I would need to have a maximal integral manifold, right? Because in this case $T_qN$ has the same dimension as $\Delta_q$. Also, I believe that N has to be compact, but I am not sure.

Comment: No, an embedded integral manifold need not be maximal (e.g., an open disk in the $(x,y)$ plane in $\mathbb R^3$ is an embedded integral manifold of the distribution spanned by $\partial/\partial x$ and $\partial/\partial y$). And a maximal integral manifold need not be either compact or embedded. A classic example is an [irrational foliation of the torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_winding_of_a_torus).

Comment: I am attempting to solve the following exercise from Boothby: "Let N be a maximal integral manifold of a distribution $\Delta$ on M. Show that if N is closed (as a subset), then it is a regular submanifold of M", but the maximal hipotesis seems unnecessary. If N is an integral manifold, it is an immersed submanifold, and if it is closed it is compact (since M is Haudorff). But an immersion from a compact space is an embedding, therefore N is a regular submanifold. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: Huh? Closed subsets of a Hausdorff space are only compact if the whole space is. Nobody said $M$ was compact. In any case, closed integral submanifolds are maximal.

Comment: (But... a mild modification of that argument *does* work!)